# Converting private Route with props from react-router v5 to react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a list of routes in `react-router v5`

```js
const agrRouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Agreements,
    exact: true,
  },
  {
    path: '/agreements/:id',
    component: AgreementPdfPage,
  },
];

export default agrRouterConfig;
```

I was passing them via custom route like this, but importantly I have important state to pass as props `setShowAgreement` :

```js
const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route: any) => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      render={(props) => (
        <route.component 
          {...props} 
          routes={route.routes} 
          setShowAgreement={route.setShowAgreement} 
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

And inside the app :

```
const Routes = () => {
  const [showAgreement, setShowAgreement] = useState(false);
///// some code 

  if (showAgreement) {
    return (
      <Switch>
        {agrRouterConfig.map((route, i) => (
          <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} setShowAgreement={setShowAgreement} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    );
  }

///// some code 
  );
};
```

What is important for me is to pass `setShowAgreement` to route as props. How to achieve that in `react-router v6`? I went through documentation, the approach is pretty different and I can't find a way to translate my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer.

`useRoutes()` from react-router v6 accepts arguments for the `router[]` object.

On my particular example:

```
// app.tsx
const App = () => {
      
    let element = useRoutes(routerConfig(setShowAgreement));
    
    return <>element </>
}
```

and inside routerObjc.tsx

```
//routerObjc.tsx
const routerConfig = (setShowAgreement?: ()=>void ) => [

  {
    path: '/documents',
    element: <Documents setShowAgreemnt={setShowAgreemnt}/>/> 
  },
  {
    path: '/profile',
    element: <Profile setShowAgreemnt={setShowAgreemnt}/> ,
  },
```